# CAS X.509 auth with attributes from database

Tags: cas

I want to configure [Apereo CAS 6.0.x](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.0.x/) to perform X.509 authentication and then retrieve principal attributes from a database table.
Rudimentary X.509 authentication is working with these lines in `application.properties` (and appropriate reverse proxy setup):

```
cas.authn.x509.extractCert=true
cas.authn.x509.sslHeaderName=SSL_CLIENT_CERT
cas.authn.x509.principalDescriptor=SUBJECT_DN
```

The default "Log In Successful" page shows that it knows how to get my certificate's subject DN.

But I can't figure out how to tell CAS to then use that subject DN value to query my database for additional attributes.

[This page](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.0.x/installation/Configuring-Principal-Resolution.html) explicitly mentions my need (though with LDAP instead of JDBC), but does not say specifically how to achieve it:

> In many cases it is necessary to perform authentication by one means and resolve principals by another. The PrincipalResolver component provides this functionality. A common use case for this this mix-and-match strategy arises with X.509 authentication. It is common to store certificates in an LDAP directory and query the directory to resolve the principal ID and attributes from directory attributes. The X509CertificateAuthenticationHandler may be be combined with an LDAP-based principal resolver to accommodate this case.

What properties need to be set so that the X509 authentication handler resolves the principal against the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing ingredient was this line in `application.properties`:

```
cas.authn.x509.principalType=SUBJECT_DN
```

Without it, CAS does not attempt to query any `attributeRepository` settings that you may have.